# Alternatives to looping through range twice

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to re-organise 4600 lines of data into a more efficient layout. Currently, i have a macro but it misses data or puts data in the wrong place.

From the old data, the column A is notification number, column FO is sheet number and GB is zone number. Whilst column C is the data that is wanting to be inputted. So currently (as the photo shows, the data is very unorganisedand unreadable.

In the outputted sheet, the notification number is put in Row 1 in columns F on wards (No duplicates). In Column B and C is zone and sheet number respectively (No duplicates). Then, using the old data, plot Column C values in the correct column(Depending on notification number) and the correct row (depending on zone and sheet number).

I have achieved half of this, but not all values are not be inputted correctly.

I currently use range.find to see if the zone number exists, and if it doesn't add the zone value and sheet number into the last used row. However, if the zone number is found but the corresponding sheet number is different, then add these values and then also add the values from column C. However, if the correct cell is filled, find the next available cell in column that is empty and input value.

But, I cant find a better way to check these values than using range.find but i feel it is missing values and not comparing both values correctly.

```
Sub GenerateTable()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim RawDataWsNotificationRng, ModifiedDataWsNotificationRng As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim RawDataWsNotificationlrow, ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcolnum, ModifiedDataWsZoneLrow As Long
Dim ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol As String
Dim serverfilename, DataSheetName, Newsheetname As String
Dim wkbk1, wkbk2 As Workbook
Dim RawDataWs, ModifiedDataWs As Worksheet
Dim FindNotificationNumber As Variant

serverfilename = InputBox("Please input name of dummy workbook (file must be open, include .xlsx")
If serverfilename = "" Then Exit Sub

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks(serverfilename)

DataSheetName = InputBox("Please enter name of sheet where data is stored")
If DataSheetName = "" Then Exit Sub

Set RawDataWs = wb2.Sheets(DataSheetName)
Set ModifiedDataWs = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

Newsheetname = InputBox("Please enter name of new sheet")
ModifiedDataWs.Name = Newsheetname

RawDataWsNotificationlrow = RawDataWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ModifiedDataWsZoneLrow = ModifiedDataWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcolnum = ModifiedDataWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol = Split(Cells(1, ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcolnum).Address, "$")(1)

Set RawDataWsNotificationRng = RawDataWs.Range("A2:A" & RawDataWsNotificationlrow)
Set ModifiedDataWsNotificationRng = ModifiedDataWs.Range("F1:" & ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol & "1")

'------------------------------------TableFeatures---------------------------------------------

With ModifiedDataWs
    .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Feature Code"
    .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Zone"
    .Cells(1, "C").Value = "Sheet"
    .Cells(1, "D").Value = "Feature Description"
    .Cells(1, "E").Value = "'-TEN OGV KH73126 tolerance"
    .Cells(1, "F").Value = "'-TEN OGV KH73126 tolerance"
    .Cells(2, "E").Value = "Nominal"
    .Cells(2, "F").Value = "Tolerance"

'------------------------------------NotificationColumns---------------------------------------------

    For Each cell In RawDataWsNotificationRng

        Set ModifiedDataWsNotificationRng = .Range("G1:" & ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol & "1")
        Set FindNotificationNumber = ModifiedDataWsNotificationRng.Find(what:=RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "A"), lookat:=xlWhole)

        If FindNotificationNumber Is Nothing Then
            ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcolnum = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol = Split(Cells(1, ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcolnum).Address, "$")(1)
            Cells(1, ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol).Value = cell.Value
        End If

    Next cell

'------------------------------------ZoneandSheetValues---------------------------------------------

Dim RawDataWsZoneRng As Variant: Set RawDataWsZoneRng = RawDataWs.Range("GB2:GB" & RawDataWsNotificationlrow)
Dim ModifiedDataWsZoneRng As Variant: Set ModifiedDataWsZoneRng = ModifiedDataWs.Range("B:B")
Dim ModifiedDataWssheetRng As Variant: Set ModifiedDataWssheetRng = ModifiedDataWs.Range("C:C")
Dim RawDataWsExtentRng As Variant: Set RawDataWsExtentRng = RawDataWs.Range("C2:C" & RawDataWsNotificationlrow)
Dim cel As Range
Dim ColumnLetterLRow, LR As Long, ColumnLetter As String, FindSheetinModifiedWs As Variant

ModifiedDataWsZoneLrow = ModifiedDataWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In RawDataWsZoneRng
    Set FindNotificationNumber = ModifiedDataWsNotificationRng.Find(what:=RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "A"), lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set FindZoneInModifiedWs = ModifiedDataWsZoneRng.Find(what:=cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set FindSheetinModifiedWs = ModifiedDataWssheetRng.Find(what:=RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "FO"), lookat:=xlWhole)
        If RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value = "CONACC" Then
            If FindZoneInModifiedWs Is Nothing Then
                LR = .Range("A:" & ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
                    .Cells(LR, FindNotificationNumber.Column).Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
                    .Cells(LR, "B").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "GB").Value
                    .Cells(LR, "C").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "FO").Value
            Else
                If Not FindZoneInModifiedWs Is Nothing And FindSheetinModifiedWs Is Nothing Then
                        LR = .Range("A:" & ModifiedDataWsNotificationlcol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
                            .Cells(LR, FindNotificationNumber.Column).Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
                            .Cells(LR, "B").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "GB").Value
                            .Cells(LR, "C").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "FO").Value
            Else
                    If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
                    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, FindNotificationNumber.Column).Address, "$")(1)
                         If (.Cells(FindZoneInModifiedWs.Row, ColumnLetter) = vbNullString) Then
                            ColumnLetterLRow = FindZoneInModifiedWs.Row
                        Else
                            Set ColumnLetterRow = .Range(ColumnLetter & FindZoneInModifiedWs.Row & ":" & ColumnLetter & "30000").Find(what:="", lookat:=xlWhole)
                                ColumnLetterLRow = ColumnLetterRow.Row
                        End If
                    .Cells(ColumnLetterLRow, FindNotificationNumber.Column).Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
                    .Cells(ColumnLetterLRow, "B").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "GB").Value
                    .Cells(ColumnLetterLRow, "C").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cell.Row, "FO").Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    ModifiedDataWsZoneLrow = ModifiedDataWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Next cell

'--------------------------Loop through zones and find input all values for zones-----------------

ModifiedDataWsZoneLrow = ModifiedDataWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set ModifiedDataWsZoneRng = ModifiedDataWs.Range("B3:B" & ModifiedDataWsZoneLrow)
Dim nextrow As Long

For Each cell In ModifiedDataWsZoneRng
    For Each cel In RawDataWsZoneRng
        If cel.Value = cell.Value Then
            Set FindNotificationNumber = ModifiedDataWsNotificationRng.Find(What:=RawDataWs.Cells(cel.Row, "A"), lookat:=xlWhole)
            Set FindZoneInModifiedWs = ModifiedDataWsZoneRng.Find(What:=cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(FindZoneInModifiedWs.Row, FindNotificationNumber.Column).Value) = True Then
                .Cells(FindZoneInModifiedWs.Row, FindNotificationNumber.Column).Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cel.Row, "C").Value
                .Cells(FindZoneInModifiedWs.Row, "B").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cel.Row, "GB").Value
                .Cells(FindZoneInModifiedWs.Row, "C").Value = RawDataWs.Cells(cel.Row, "FO").Value
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
Next cell
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated! sorry i am new to VBA!

Old Data Sheet

[image]

New Sheet

[image]

Link to workbook

[Link to workbook](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnQEPbEJrVkoj15VQNrkh303BRLw?e=30ChRC)

Comment: Please edit and simplify you question - I'm not sure what you're asking. You say *"(as the photo shows, the data is very readable and unreadable."* - what do you mean by this? Very readable *and* unreadable?

Comment: "In Column B and C is zone and sheet number respectively (No duplicates)" in your screenshot it looks like there are duplicate rows here - eg rows 8-10

Comment: I think I see what you're doing.  I would 1. Create a scripting dictionary with a composite key of Zone+Sht#+Notification# and use that to track how many rows you need for each unique pair of Zone+sheet.  At the same time use another dictionary to track Notification# and column number (populate Row1 as you build that).  Create the column B/C entries from the first dictionary.  Then loop over your data and populate the values in the matrix, using your two dictionaries to locate the appropriate cell

Comment: If you can share a workbook with data (only need the 4 columns of interest) I will take a stab at it.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the duplicates, tey are meant to be there. They are put in after to fill the space where several values have been enetered for C15 sheet 3 in a certain column(This example 3 entries)

Comment: Hi Tim, i have added a link to a workbook in the post at th bottom! thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that more more complex than i'd thought but here goes:

```
'type to manage data we use from each row
Type dataRow
    notif As Variant
    variable As Variant
    sht As Variant
    zone As Variant
End Type

Sub DoPivot()
    Const SEP As String = "<>"
    Dim rngData As Range, data, r As Long
    Dim colDict As Object, rowDict As Object, comboDict As Object
    Dim rd As dataRow, rngOutput As Range, col As Long, rw As Long, k
    Dim k2, arr, dictCounts As Object
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet, num As Long

    Set colDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rowDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set comboDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dictCounts = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    data = Sheet9.Range("A2:D4788").Value 'source data

    Set rngOutput = Sheet9.Range("H1")    'top-left cell for output
    Set wsOut = rngOutput.Parent

    rngOutput.Resize(5000, 5000).ClearContents

    rngOutput.Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("Sheet", "Zone")

    col = rngOutput.Column + 2 'start for notification# headers
    rw = rngOutput.row + 1

    'first pass - assess data variables
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        rd = rowData(data, r)
        k = Join(Array(rd.sht, rd.zone, rd.notif), SEP) 'tracking how many unique combinations of these
        comboDict(k) = comboDict(k) + 1 'increment count
        'manage column header positions for unique notification numbers
        If Not colDict.exists(rd.notif) Then
            colDict.Add rd.notif, col 'store the column
            rngOutput.EntireRow.Cells(1, col).Value = rd.notif 'add the header
            col = col + 1
        End If
    Next r

    'figure out # of rows for each sheet-Zone pair
    For Each k In comboDict.keys
        arr = Split(k, SEP)
        k2 = Join(Array(arr(0), arr(1)), SEP) 'sheet<>zone
        'is this more rows than any previous same k2 value?
        dictCounts(k2) = Application.Max(dictCounts(k2), comboDict(k))
    Next k

    'create the row headers
    For Each k In dictCounts.keys
        num = dictCounts(k)
        rowDict(k) = rw         'record start row for each sheet<>zone combo
        wsOut.Cells(rw, rngOutput.Column).Resize(num, 2).Value = Split(k, SEP)
        dictCounts(k) = 0 'reset so we can track while adding data
        rowDict(k) = rw
        rw = rw + num
    Next k

    'last pass - populate the data based on the dictionaries
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        rd = rowData(data, r)
        k = Join(Array(rd.sht, rd.zone, rd.notif), SEP) '3-field combo
        k2 = Join(Array(rd.sht, rd.zone), SEP)          'row key

        wsOut.Cells(rowDict(k2) + (dictCounts(k)), _
                    colDict(rd.notif)).Value = rd.variable

        dictCounts(k) = dictCounts(k) + 1               'increment this unique combo

    Next r

End Sub

'populate a Type instance for a given row
Function rowData(data, r As Long) As dataRow
    Dim rv As dataRow
    rv.notif = IfEmpty(data(r, 1))
    rv.variable = IfEmpty(data(r, 2))
    rv.sht = IfEmpty(data(r, 3))
    rv.zone = IfEmpty(data(r, 4))
    rowData = rv
End Function

'substitute EMPTY for zero-length value
Function IfEmpty(v)
    IfEmpty = IIf(Len(v) = 0, "EMPTY", v)
End Function
```

**EDIT**: if you want to filter out certain rows then you need to modify the loops which iterate over `data`

```
For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
    If data(r, colHere) <> "X" Then '<<  add your filter here
        rd = rowData(data, r) 

        'rest of code as before...

    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I can understand a lot of the code  and it makes logical sense completly. I will test the code out to test if its fully functioning. But this looks amazing. Scripting dictionaries is something i have never been able to get my head around. Just like to say a big thank you for your effort! I will let you know the results!

Comment: Quick question, if i wanted to add an if statement in, e.g. ignore cells and values that have "X" in column ... Row ..., where would be the best place to put this and what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hi Tim,  Just an Update! The macro is working perfectly, its so good and much better method than what i proposed so thank you very much! Quick question, sometimes the columns are in a different order, so i want to add a function in that finds the correct column first instead of specifiy the column as done in RowData function. how would i do this and where would i put the function? I have tried but i get Argument is not optional error

Comment: If headers are always the same text then you can use either Find() or Match() on Row1 to find their location - you can either do that in `rowData` or in separate method (you don't want to be doing that for every row of data)